# XamlParseException at default style Setter for custom control property

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls, winrt-xaml, xamlparseexception

Please forgive the obtuse title, not sure how best to phrase my problem...

I have written a custom control "CustomControl" in project Foo. It has a dependency property "Title" which is a string:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Title",
         typeof(string),
         typeof(CustomControl),
         PropertyMetadata.Create("Default Title")
    );
public string Title
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
}
```

In my Generic.xaml file, I am trying to set the value of "Title" with a Setter node:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">

    <!-- Setter for Template property -->

    <Setter Property="Title" Value="Any String" />
</Style>
```

The app chokes as soon as it tries to render the control, saying it cannot find the "Title" property in my control:

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in Foo.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: The property 'Title' was not found in type 'Foo.Controls.CustomControl'. [Line: X Position: Y]
>
> Additional information: Unspecified error

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this not allowed?
When I break in the debugger I can **see** the Title property on the object, so I'm pretty perplexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel silly and it may be best that this question just be deleted, because after hours of hair pulling I solved it 10 seconds after posting the question.

The problem was in my DependencyProperty.Register call. I had the owner type (third argument) referencing a class with a very similar name, and not actually the owning class. Oops. :(

Comment: Don't delete. I just did this too. ;)